# How can i validate a list of emails in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a list of emails that get sent from the client side which are seperated by a comma. How can i validate all these emails to ensure that they are valid emails? e.g a user can capture emails in a text box like this *one@one.com, two@two.com,three@three.com* etc

Answer (score 1):

I built a similar functionality at some point by using customer validation functions

```
Validator::extend("emails", function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        $rules = ['email' => 'required|email'];
        $emails = array_map('trim', explode(';', $value)); //$value
        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $data = ['email' => $email];
            $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Where do i implement this?

Comment: You have to implement this in App/Providers directory. By default there are other provider files like auth, app, service, event etc therefore you can create one for validation - at least that's where i put mine!

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to validate an array of emails then easiest way to validate is to use dot `.` syntax with a wildcard `*`. Here's the example:

```
$request->validate([
    'emails.*' => ['email'],
    ...
]);
```